# Why are there chords that aren't a third away form the root considered chromatic mediants?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, terminology

For example, take a C chord. One of the requirements for a chord to be a chromatic mediant is that it is a major/minor third away from the root. So why are chords like Cm, Fm, C♯ and F♯ considered chromatic mediants as well?

Comment: Can you give an example of where you've heard those chords referred to in such a way? I've never encountered that. However, all of those chords contain the mediant or submediant *pitches* (E/Eb, A/Ab) relative to C major/minor.

Comment: I was reading an article from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_mediant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding of a chromatic mediant relationship is correct, so the chords you listed do **not** of have a chromatic mediant relationship to C major.

However, those four chords (Cm, Fm, C♯, F♯) all have roots a third away from A. A minor is the **relative minor** of C major, which means the two keys share the same key signature. So I think the source you were reading was listing out the chromatic mediants for the relative minor.

Comment: I see. It just happens that those chords share similar notes with C major. Does this mean that every chord has their own chromatic mediant?

Comment: @MiaLee That's correct -- every chord has it's own set of chromatic mediants, based on the root of the primary chord.